# Dynamically Add <a> to Embedded SVG

Tags: javascript, xml, html, svg

The script snippet below is for an svg embedded in an html document. The issue  is that the svgMap.appendChild(cL); bit throws an error says appendChild is not a function which is ridiculous.

```
    var svgMap = document.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    console.log(svgMap);
    var cId = document.getElementById(county[j][0]);
    var cL = document.createElementNS(null,"a");
    cL.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", "http://mtent.org/");
    svgMap.appendChild(cL);
    cL.appendChild(cId);
    console.log(cL);
    cId.setAttribute("class", "county");
    console.log(document.getElementById(county[j][0]));
```

Comment: SVG elements like "a" need to be created in the SVG namespace and not the null namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg")[0]
```

notice the [0] ... getElementsByTagName returns a collection ;-)